# Can using gParted let me use my failed windows flash drive?

Tags: windows-7, flash, gparted, usb-drive

So a Windows 7 thumb-drive I made just resulted into a blinkung-cursor and nothing else. But before I delete it, can I use GParted to mount it to a partition on my HD?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use "udevadm monitor" then plug in your drive, it will show you what dev device it is created as. Then use "mount / dev/sdx /mnt" where x is the drive it was created as in the dev directory to mount it on /mnt